# Can a website distinguish between a web scraper and a legitimate user on a basis other than the speed of traversal?

Tags: screen-scraping

If I reduce the speed of a web scraper to match the speed of a human, will a third party be able to distinguish between them? What other criteria do websites use to distinguish between users and scrapers

Comment: Is this not the right site to ask this question? Can you please suggest the appropriate site

Comment: The scraper will have a hostname that is on a certain list. It may have the identity of a scraper, similar to that your identity will be what browser you use. There are plenty of different ways to identify a scraper, but this is indeed not the right site to ask this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many criteria a web site *could* use to identify possible scrapers.  Some are more prone to false positives than others.

- User agent. Many scrapers have a `User-Agent:` header which readily and reliably identifies them.  Many of the following characteristics can also be correlated with the `User-Agent:` to check whether the postulated user agent's behavior actually matches what is expected from the graphical browser it may be trying to appear as.
- IP ranges. For example, a bot operating out of Google or Amazon cloud IP address space is probably automated (or a VPN exit node).
- Traversal timing. A trivial bot will visit site-internal links with a fixed delay between "clicks", or with a variation which is so small as to fail to masquerade as a real user.
- Traversal order. A trivial bot will visit the site-internal links in the order it discovers them, while a user will only visit a small number of links in a less predictable order.
- Image downloads. A human using a graphical browser will exhibit somewhat predictable bursts of parallel connections, somewhat also depending on the available bandwidth and the browser's configuration. But many bots will only fetch one page at a time, and perhaps bypass graphics entirely.
- JavaScript behavior. A real browser with JavaScript enabled will execute JavaScript payloads. Some scraping bots attempt to emulate this, but many don't, and those which do often do an imperfect job.
- Alternate paths. The HTML source may contain links in sections which will not be exposed in a particular browser with a particular configuration; but a trivial bot will visit both hidden and exposed links.